# Grails push to Heroku failed - applicationContext.xml doesn't exist

Tags: grails, heroku, grails-2.0

I try to deploy my Grails 2.1.1 application to Heroku.

I run `git push master heroku` and it runs for a while (compiles alright, get dependencies, ec), then it gives me this message:

```
|Building WAR file
   ...........................Error 
   |
   Error executing script War: : Replace: source file /app/.grails/2.1.1/projects/Project/stage/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml doesn't exist (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
 !     Failed to build app
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Grails app
```

When I run `grails war` locally, it works without any issues.

I have done some reading but I haven't found a solid answer. Similar issues that I have read about have been caused by JDK-related issues, or plugins.

Comment: What version of grails are you using locally? Can you run a one-off command on your dyno to check if applicationContext.xml exists?

Comment: when you do git status, are there any files that are not checked in or in your ignore list?

Comment: @tomas git status tells me I have no changes. The ignore list was taken från GitHub.

Comment: @culix Locally I'm not sure, I'll have to double check. How do I give the command?

Comment: @marko To check the version try `grails -version` - [see here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html)

Comment: @culix well, that gave me 2.1.1 as I wrote in the question. But one thing I noticed (I use STS) that it compiles with 2.0.4 according to my preferences. Any ideas?

Comment: @marko Sorry I mistyped - I meant to ask: what version of the Heroku Toolbelt are you using? `heroku --version`

Comment: @culix I don't really know how to check that, spoon feed me pls :)

Comment: @culix this is what heroku --version gave me:
heroku-toolbelt/2.35.0 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3

Comment: I just noted that the path supplied in the error message is a reference to my local dev env. Shouldn't it look for it in a war-file?

Comment: For the record, I found this : http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/grails-war-applicationContext-xml-doesn-t-exist-td1334855.html but I had already tried upgrade and it didn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution in this case was to add WEB-INF to my repository. By the default my .gitignore (created via GitHub) ignores WEB-INF.

Comment: This helped me deploy to ElasticBeanstalk from Travis too.  Thanks!

Comment: Great, that also helped me on Grails 2.3.7. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it guys! Keep using Grails!

Comment: THANK YOU.  I was trying to deploy to Heroku and this helped me.

Comment: @anataliocs glad to hear it! So annoying, can't believe how little you can find online.